# When is a fragment loaded..or at least when is its adapter done binding

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I can't seem to figure out how to know when a cursoradapter has completed all its binding.

ie. I'd like to execute something, but only after a fragment is fully populated.
I set its listadapter to my custom cursoradapter
I use the bindview and newview methods in the cursoradapter.
I was hoping for a method something like "bindingcompleted"..

From simple logcat outputs, i get the [subset] lifecycle as:

```
activity onCreate
fragment ViewCreated
fragment ActivityCreated (where i initiate my cursoradapter/loader)
fragment onStart
activity onStart
fragment newview (cursoradapter)
fragment bindview (cursoradapter)
[repeat above two for each row in cursor data/list]
```

so it seems the fragment and activity are actually made visible to the user before the binding completes.. which is fine.. but how do i know when it's done?
ideas?  am i missing a good method to override?

Comment: i thought about running a query somewhere (ie.fragment.activitycreated) getting the number of records coming.. then increment a count during the bind call.. if the count is equal to the records, then i know we are done.

Comment: binding is never "complete" as `bindView` is called once for each item visible on the screen, then again when you scroll and a view needs to change its underlying data at that position

Comment: tell me what you want to do when the listview has finished drawing and I might be able to tell you why it's a bad idea :-) or if there is another way

Comment: and my thought above is a hack.. and not sure how it would handle updated data in the backend (And scrolling as you say)..   what I'd like to do once the listview is done drawing, is let another fragment know it's complete, so it can kick off something.  if the data is updated, thats fine, i'd jsut tell the other fragment to start over too

Comment: In bindView you can get the Cursor position and compare it to the last visible position

Comment: i think i may abandon the idea.. now that i realize the scrolling part too..

Comment: getting the Cursor position will work with scrolling too

Comment: thanks yeah.. but i was thinking all the data would have been obtained.. forgot about the 'visible' part. sorry.. i'll work it another way. thanks!